# Implement browser NVR

Tags: web, html5-video, file-system-access-api

The simplest abstraction of NVR(Network Video Recorder) is like the follow:

1. The user specifies a path (such as: ~/recrods/) to store video records.
2. The NVR creates video files (such as: 1.mp4, 2.mp4) on the path.

Now we are going to implement a web-page NVR. Is it possible to do the similar things in the browser without popping up file selectors?

Comment: Browsers can open files via a file selector, but it sounds like you want to save files there?  I think you need to explain more about where the video comes from and where it should be saved (your server, client computer, 3rd-party site, etc)

Comment: We could ignore the video stream part. Now we just can't save file silently from the browser. But it seems that https://vscode.dev can do it. How?